# Dart reader.on.loadEnd error

Tags: dart, dart-io

do anyone know what is wrong on this code?

```dart
FileReader reader = new FileReader();
reader.on.loadEnd.add(fileLoader);
```

Error: Breaking on exception: Class 'Events' has no instance getter 'loadEnd'.

Answer (score 3):

it should be like

```dart
reader.onLoadEnd.listen(fileLoader); 
// or reader.onLoadEnd.listen((e) => fileLoader(e)); // don't know what your fileLoader is exactly
```

or alternatively

```dart
reader.on['load-end'].listen(fileLoader);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I looked at examples: http://c.dart-examples.com/api/dart-html/interface/eventtarget/filereader but there are invalid examples I'm afraid. Anyway your examples will not threw any error, but it still does not work I'm afraid and event in loadEnd never happen in my project :-(

Comment: I don't think this is an official Dart site. The syntax has changed about a year ago. If something doesn't work as expected you can Ctrl+click on a class or method to jump to its definition and verify what it returns and read the code comments to learn more. If you use DartEditor it should show you where the error is.